# Javascript not working in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: html, iframe, internet-explorer-11

We're having an issue with our page not working on Internet Explorer 11. However, it works fine on other browsers with no issues.

We don't know how to solve this and we've been researching on the internet on how to fix this issue however, cannot find anything which can help.

We were wondering if anyone could assist us with this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Canon UST Demo</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0"/>
<!--<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> -->

    <!-- Add jQuery library -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="./jquery.reel.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="raphael.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="mainJ.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.event.move.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.twentytwenty.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="default.css">
<link href="jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="twentytwenty.css">
<style type="text/css">
.forMidSec{width:100%; float: left; text-align: center;}
.marked {
    background: red; width: 20px;height: 20px;  
    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    }

    #openDiv
    {
        z-index:99;
    }
    .AF
    {
        display:none;
    }

    .innerPages .inFP
    {
        display:none;
    }
    .commonHeader
    {
        visibility:hidden;
    }


</style>
</head>
<body>
<!---->
<div class="imainint">
    <div id = "imgwrap" class="imgwrapint">
        <div id="introimg" style="width:800px;height:670px;">

        </div>

    </div>
</div>
<!---->
<div class="progressBar">
<div class="progressImg"></div>
</div>
<div class="mainWrap">
<header class="mainHead">
<div class="wrapper clearfix modelName">
<div class="col1">
<ul class="top">
<li id ="mainli"><a href="#" class="mainBuy" title="Buy" target="_blank"><img src="buynow.png" alt="Buy Now" /></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="col3"><img src="logo_canon.png" width="70" height="15" alt="Canon"></div>
</div>

</header>

<div class="forMidSec">
<section class="wrapper clearfix h600">
<!--<span class="dtext">HTYU</span>-->
<div id="showImages">
<div id="view360wrapper">
        <!-- Image 360 Deg to show here -->
        <img src="360/1-1.jpg" name="view360" id="view360"/>
    </div></div>

    <div id="openDiv" style="display:none">
    <ul class="sub-menu">
    </ul>
   </div>


  <div id ="omni_arrow"><img src="omni-arrow.png" alt="omni-arrow" style="text-align:center"></div>

  </div>
  </section>
  </div>
 <div class="commonHeader"> 
    <header>
    <div class="wrapper clearfix modelName">
    <div class="col1">
    <ul class="top">
    <li><a href="#" class="commonBack" title="Back"><img src="back.gif" alt="Back"></a></li>
    <li id = "buyLi"><a href="#" class="buyLink" title="Buy" target="_blank"><img src="buynow.png" alt="Buy Now"></a></li>
    <li class="compareBtn"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="cmpTxt" title="Compare">Compare</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col2">
<ul class="top">
<li></li>
<li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="openFeatureBox" title="Specifications"><img class="featureImg" src="" alt=""></a><a href="javascript:void(0)"> <img src="specifications.gif" alt="Specifications" class="featureSpecs"></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
    <div class="col3"><img src="logo_canon.png" width="70" height="15" alt="Canon"></div>
    </div>

    </header>
 </div>
 <div class="innerPages">

 <div id="openCompare" class="compare-overlay">
<div class="compare-open">
<div class="compare-arrow"></div>
<a title="Close" href="javascript:void(0)" class="compare-close"></a>
<div class="compare-inner">
<div class="compare-innerTop">

</div>
<div class="compare-innerBottom">

</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div id="openFeatures" class="features-overlay">
<div class="features-open">
<div class="features-arrow"></div>
<a title="Close" href="javascript:void(0)" class="features-close"></a>
<div class="features-inner">

<p>Language Text</p>
</div>
</div>
</div> 

<!-- Start of auto focus Images --> 
 <div class="AF inFP">
<section class="wrapper clearfix bgcol3 h600">
  <div class="wrapper clearfix bgcol1">
    <div class="hotspot-gallery">  
        <div class="big-image"></div>
         <div class="hotSpotImg"></div>  
    </div>
    </div>
</section>
  </div>
 <!-- End of auto focus Images --> 

 <!-- Start of video Page -->
 <div class="videoContainer inFP">
 <section class="wrapper clearfix bgcol1 h600">
 <div class="progressBar">
    <div class="progressImg"></div>
</div>
<div class="vid">
<video width="640"  id="eosVid" height="360" controls>
  <source src="" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
</div>
</section>
</div>
 <!-- End Of Video page -->

 <!-- Start of Overlap feature -->
 <div class="overlapContainer inFP">
 <section class="wrapper clearfix h600">
 <div class="overlapCont"></div>

</section> 
</div>
 <!-- End of Overlap feature -->

  <!-- Start of HDR Gallery feature -->
 <div class="hdrGalCont inFP">
 <section class="wrapper clearfix bgcol3 h600">
       <div id="openEnlargeImg" class="EnlargeImg-overlay">
            <div class="EnlargeImg-open">
            <a title="Close" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="document.getElementById('openEnlargeImg').style.display='none'" class="EnlargeImg-close"></a>
            <div class="EnlargeImg-inner">
            <img src="EOS 70D - HDR - Normal Exposure.jpg" /> </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="image-gallery">
           <div class="enlargeIcon filterImg"><a href="javascript:void(0)"><img src="fullbutton.png"></a></div>
           <div class="big-image">           
           </div>  

          <div class="captionTxt"></div>

         <div class="thumbs">  
         <ul>    

         </ul>
         </div>

</div>
 </section>  
</div>
 <!-- End of Hdr Gallery feature -->

 <!-- Start of Filter Gallery feature -->
 <div class="filterGal inFP">
 <div id="openEnlargeImg1" class="EnlargeImg-overlay">
            <div class="EnlargeImg-open">
            <a title="Close" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="document.getElementById('openEnlargeImg1').style.display='none'" class="EnlargeImg-close"></a>
            <div class="EnlargeImg-inner">
            <img src="EOS 70D - HDR - Normal Exposure.jpg" /> </div>
            </div>
        </div>

 <section class="wrapper clearfix bgcol1">
     <div class="imgWrapper filterGalFlow"></div>    
</section>   
</div>
 <!-- End of Filter Gallery feature -->

  <!-- Start of MultiExpo  feature -->
 <div class="MultiExposure inFP">
 <section class="wrapper clearfix h600">
      <div class="multipleExpo"><img src="" alt="Multiple Exposure" style="max-width:800px; height:auto"></div>     
</section>
      </div>
 <!-- End of MultiExpo feature -->

 <div class="frameSlier inFP">

<div class="slide-img">
    <div id="cycler" class="eagleSlide">
    <!--<img class="active" src="" alt="My image" />    
    <img src="" alt="My image" />   
    <img src="" alt="My image" />
    <img src="" alt="My image" />
    <img src="" alt="My image" />
    <img src="" alt="My image" />
    <img src="" alt="My image" />
    <img src="" alt="My image" />
    <img src="" alt="My image" />
    <img src="" alt="My image" /> -->
   </div>

   <div class="sliderBg">
   <div id="slider">

   </div>
   </div>
</div>   

 </div><!-- End of Frame Slider-->

 <!-- Start of HdrSlider -->
 <div class="hdrSlider inFP">

    <div class="slide-img">
   <div id="cycler2">
    <img class="active" src="" alt="My image" />    
    <img src="" alt="My image" />   
    <img src="" alt="My image" />
   </div>

   <div id="slider2Up">
   <div id="slider2">

   </div>
   </div>
</div> 
 </div><!-- End Of hdr Slider-->

 <!-- Start of zoom slider -->
 <div class="zoomSlider inFP">
        <div class="slide-img">
   <div id="cycler3">

   </div>

   <div id="slider3Up">
   <div id="slider3">

   </div>
   </div>
</div>  
 </div>
<!-- End of zoom slider -->

<!-- Start of Dual Slider -->
<div class="dualSlid inFP">
<div class="slide-img dualSlideImg">


</div>

<div style="width:800px; height:auto; display:table; margin:-80px auto  0; padding:0; position:relative">   

   <div style="width:49%; display:table-cell">
   <div id="slider5Up">
   <div id="slider5"></div>
   </div>
   </div>

   <div style="width:49%; display:table-cell">
   <div id="slider4Up">
   <div id="slider4">

   </div>
   </div>

   </div>

</div>

</div>
<!-- End of dual Slider-->

</div> 
    <div id="clickLinks"></div>
    <div id="videoPlayer"></div>
    <div id="staticImageViewer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is not working exactly ?

Comment: it doesn't display the product. It just shows the loading screen but not the actual interface. This doesn't happen with Chrome, Firefox or Safari only on internet explorer.

Comment: What does the console say?

Comment: Weirdly it doesn't present any errors at all. But the interface doesn't load, I'm not sure what is wrong. I've read online that IE 11 doesn't support iFrames or execute javascript correctly. So I'm lost on ideas.